# Inflate a layout into another layout (or convert the layout to a view and then inflate the view)

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to inflate a layout multiple times using a loop into another layout. the java is fine when i inflate a TextView or any other single view.  but i want to inflate this entire layout.   What method do i use for this because the following code wont work. (like i said, the loop and all is fine, its just i cant inflate an entire layout. I only know how to inflate a simple view).

```
View childInflatedView = (View) theInflater.inflate(R.id.restaurant_displayed_on_list, null);
linLayout.addView(childInflatedView);
```

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
android:id="@+id/restaurant_displayed_on_list" >

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="this is the inflated text"
    android:textColor="#990099"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<Button    
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background= "@drawable/delete"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit1:**

As stated by Matthew, I think the solution is to inflate the layout by layout resource ID.
The problem I think lies in this line of code not shown above since the layout cannot be cast to a TextView:

```
View categoryInflatedView1 = (View) theInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_available, null);

((TextView) categoryInflatedView1).setText(category1);          

linLayout.addView(categoryInflatedView1);
```

How do i access the TextView that lies inside of the layout. I need to edit the textview before inflating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the *layout* resource ID instead. Replace `R.id.restaurant_displayed_on_list` with `R.layout.<name of your layout file here>` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thats what i was doing before. Im thinking since it is cast to a view it doesnt work for some reason. Maybe layout cant be cast to view????

Comment: I was being retarded. The problem was that i was casting the layout to a (textview) instead of finding view by id first

Answer (score 1):

So the reason that this wasn't working was 2 fold.

You simply inflate the layout via  layout resource ID as stated by Mathew

```
View childInflatedView = (View) theInflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_available, null);
```

I was having an extra error that i found in the log due to casting the layout to a TextView
Instead, i must use this code to make it work (layout variable then find view by id):

```
((TextView) childInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_displayed_on_list)).setText(currentlyDelRest1);
```

Although this answer is correct, I am going to assign the accepted answer to Mathew since his answer was correct given the information available in the question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<include>` tag. It includes another XML layout within an existing one.For ex, adding the below two lines will include two other layouts in your parent layout:

```
 <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
<include android:id="@+id/cell2" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
```

In the  only the layout attribute is required. This attribute, without the android namespace prefix, is a reference to the layout file you wish to inflate. You can also use `android:id` to specify the id of the root view of the included layout; it will also override the id of the included layout if one is defined. Similarly, you can override all the layout parameters.

Comment: so you are saying use this to include another view in XML? the problem is i must loop through an unknown number of objects and then inflate the views based on those object.  I cant just say "include for 7 items".  any advice on how i can continue with the layout inflater for an actual layout file instead of just a view?